# How can I force Uri to use the baseUri?

Tags: c#, .net-core, uri

There seems to be a major problem with using the Uri class with base URIs. For some reason it's a "feature" that if a relative URI is passed in and it appears to be a full URL, the Uri class will ignore the baseUri and just use the relative Uri instead. This can be a security vulnerability and I'd like to understand how to avoid it but still gain the features of combining base and relative URIs to create a single URL in C# dotnetcore.

In the example below you can see that a relative uri of `http://badexample.com` makes the baseUri not appear in the generated URI. This is dangerous.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var baseUri = new Uri("http://google.com");
        var relativeUri = new Uri(baseUri, "search?q=stuff");
        Console.WriteLine(relativeUri);

        var badUri = new Uri(baseUri, "http://badexample.com");
        Console.WriteLine(badUri);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
http://google.com/search?q=stuff
http://badexample.com/
```

Comment: You can use `IsBaseOf` to determine if one is the base of another. It's a workaround but seems to help avoid security problems

Comment: What's the output you're expecting? `http://google.com/http://badexample.com`?

Comment: @Magnetron That would be acceptable output (possibly url encoded though)

Comment: Then check if my answer suits you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could escape the `:`:

```
string relativeUrl = "http://badexample.com";
var badUri = new Uri(baseUri, relativeUrl.Replace(":","%3A"));
```

This will produce `http://google.com/http%3A//badexample.com`

About security, [Microsoft docs recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1#security-considerations), when dealing with user input, to do the following validation:

```
if (!Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, userInput, out Uri newUri))
{
    // Fail: invalid input.
}

if (!baseUri.IsBaseOf(newUri))
{
    // Fail: the Uri base has been modified - the created Uri is not rooted in the original directory.
}
```

Comment: I think the 2nd part of your answer is an acceptable solution. The first part is probably not a great suggestion because it is a non-standard way of encoding a url